# Display Calendar/Notes entries with raspberry pi?

Tags: http, lotus-notes, extract

I want to realise the following:

I'm using Lotus Notes 9 to manage my meetings, mails etc..
As a project, I want to display the meeting entries in my calendar with a raspberry pi on another display, somewhere else in my house.

So my question is:
Is it possible to get this Informations from my Calendar/Notes via HTTP e.g. and display it with an raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Lotus] IBM Notes only, then this is not possible automatically: You could export your calendar entries as iCal and import them in an appropriate app on the raspberry. But this is a manual process. If you have an IBM Domino Server, then you could enable the new Calendar Web Service and just use that with an app.

With access to Domino designer you could write some code for your IBM Notes Client that "syncs" the data somehow whenever you start the Notes- Client, but that needs quite good knowledge of coding in IBM Notes.